# installed Local Enviroment get "unresolvable": env.current_time error

Tags: smart-contract

as stated in the topic, i installed eosio new because i had a few problems with the older Version with actions in actions and now i get this error everytime i want to create a contract on the chain.

Error:

Publishing contract.....

Error 3030000: transaction validation exception

Ensure that your transaction satisfy the contracts's constraint!

Error Details:

!"unresolvable": env.current_time

Answer (score 1):

Deleted all EOSIO Files on my system and made a clean reinstall and everything works again. Don't know where Problem was but i think somewhere in the update Process something gone wrong.